# How to Get tables of every element in an array in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an application that uses lots of logic to cross-multiply elements of different arrays, But now I have to get the tables printed of an array, which I am finding difficult to do so in Dart language. So hence I decided to consult StackOverflow

Comment: you can use the map method to map over the list element and execute the function that make the table for each element

Comment: can you please add an example and the expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself...

```
void main (){
  List list = [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
   for(int i = 0; i< list.length; i++){
    print(" ");
    for(int a = 1; a<=10; a++){
      print("${a*list[i]} ");`
        }
             }
```